# Video capture of an external USB webcam with python cv2 (on Windows)

Tags: python, windows, webcam, video-capture, opencv

I am trying to capture a video via python (cv2) from an external usb webcam (Logitec c922 pro stream) on Windows.
In order to verify that the connection is working even for an image capture, I tried the following code:

## ___________________________________

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
while True:
    s, img = cam.read()   
    picName = 'pic.png'
    cv2.imwrite(picName, img)
```

## ___________________________________

When I run this code, a dialog box opens to choose between the 2 external cameras connected. When I choose the Logitec camera, it is turned on but the saved images are black, which is not what the camera views.

1. Can I skip the dialog box part and choose the Logitec camera via the code?
2. How can I capture actual images from the external webcam?

Comment: Have you tried different lighting conditions? Maybe the camera exposure is not set correctly. Also you might want to check using 0, 1, or 2 instead of -1 as an argument for "VideoCapture". Check this link : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12260

Comment: Thank you @maf88_. The lightning was fine, as I did capture good images with the Windows app. I tried using 0 as an argument before and it didn't work, but it did work with **1**, so thanks a lot  :)